# Jquery selecting elements inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow code:

```
var table1 = $('[id="table1"]');
var table2 = $('[id="table2"]');
```

I need to get inside each table the text content from specified id as this:

```
var words1 = $('[id^="table-row-"]');
var words2 = $('[id^="table-row-"]');
```

Please note that `id^="table-row-"` because it is variable as for example "**table-row-1**", "**table-row-2**", etc.

I tried something like this but it does not works:

```
var words1 = $('[id^="table-row-"]').table1;
```

What I need to do?

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use the `#` to find IDs:

```
var $table1 = $('#table-1');
```

You can space separate child selectors like so:

```
var $table1row1 = $('#table-1 #table-row-1');
```

Or, if you have your initial jQuery object cached, you can perform a `$.find()`:

```
var $table1 = $('#table-1'),
    $tableRow1 = $table.find('#table-row-1');
```

However, IDs should *always* be unique to the entire document. Never use the same ID on more than one element. If you have an ID called `table-row-1`, that should be the *only* time that ID appears in the document, and you can simply do:

```
var $tableRow1 = $('#table-row-1');
```

I believe your HTML should probably look more like this:

```
<table id="table-1">
  <tr class="table-row-1">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row-2">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table-2">
  <tr class="table-row-1">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row-2">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So you have classes that are reusable across multiple tables, and then you can do finds for the table rows in each table.

```
$table1row1 = $('#table-1 .table-row-1');
```

Also note that if you're just incrementing the rows, you can also [find elements by their index](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) within the parent element. So, given the above HTML:

```
$('#table-one tr').eq(1); // returns the first tr element in #table-one
```

Note: it's customary when storing jQuery objects to preface the variable name with a `$` to connote that it's a referencing a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

you can access by there index

```
 $('[id^="table-row-"]')[0]
 $('[id^="table-row-"]')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For all rows:

```
var words1 = $('[id="table1"] [id^="table-row-"]');
var words2 = $('[id="table2"] [id^="table-row-"]');
```

For one row:

```
var words1 = $('[id="table1"] [id="table-row-' + id + '"]');
var words2 = $('[id="table2"] [id="table-row-' + id + '"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the native (non-jQuery) querySelector?

```
var table = document.querySelector("table");
var row = table.querySelector("tr");
var cell = row.querySelector("td");
alert(cell.innerHTML);
```

...or, if you insist on using jQuery:

```
var $tables = $("table");
var $rows = $($tables[0]).find("tr");
var $cells = $($rows[0]).find("td");
alert($($cells[0]).html());
```

That's slightly different because jQuery returns all elements (in the above example, using $(xxx[0]) to get the first instance).  If you want to find all instances the native way, use querySelectorAll.